# how do i solve this Build failed in adroid studio?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, build.gradle

I keep getting Build failed each time i try to run my app in android studio.
here is what i get each time i run the app

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.3-6040484.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.3-6040484 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.3-6040484 available for offline mode.

Please can somebody help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to disable gradle offline mode and try again